# What is the XPath expression to select a Processing instruction?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm using `xsl:stylesheet` Processing Instruction in my XML. Is there anyway to select this PI using XPath ? If so how ?

Answer (score 10):

In general, a processing instruction can be selected using the `processing-instruction()` node test.

More specifically, one can include as argument the name (target) of the wanted PI node.

**Use**:

```
/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')
```

This selects any processing instruction with name `xsl-stylesheet` that is defined at the global level (is sibling of the top element).

Do note that `xsl:stylesheet` is an invalid PI target for a PI. A colon `':'` is used to delimit a namespace prefix from the local name -- however a processing instruction *target* cannot belong to a namespace. As per the **[W3c XPath Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Processing-Instruction-Nodes)**:

"*A processing instruction has an expanded-name: the local part is the processing instruction's target; the namespace URI is null*."

Also according to the W3C document: **["Associating Style Sheets with XML documents 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/)**", the target of the PI that associates a stylesheet to an XML document must be: `"xml-stylesheet"` -- not `"xsl:stylesheet"` or `"xsl-stylesheet"` .

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied against the following XML document**:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test"?>
<Books>
    <Book name="MyBook" />
</Books>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected PI node is output**:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test"?>
```

Comment: I see you're still up to your old tricks... Deleting and re-posting an answer to discard down-votes is straight up abuse: how folks decide to rate your answers is their decision, not yours. Please refrain from doing this again.

Comment: Does `/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')` select things with name `xsl-stylesheet`? That would be magic! Note `xml` vs `xsl`.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter, Yes, it does. This is formally defined here (the third paragraph from the bottom): http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter, No, it doesn't. Not sure why Dimitre believes otherwise, but I've tested this, and it won't match.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter, Flynn1179 is right -- I didn't see the difference in names. But you can easily do: `processing-instruction()[name() = 'xml-stylesheet' or name()='xsl-stylesheet']`

Comment: @Flynn1179, Yes, I didn't notice that the comment was asking for selecting a PI with another name. I replied with another comment, specifying one way to select both such PIs.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`processing-instruction()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) node-test.

Comment: Kirill, this answer is too general -- you are not providing a specific XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted PI.

Answer (score 0):

A processing-instruction hat two parts target and data with the syntax:

```
<?target data?>
```

If you use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')" />
```

It will only return the data part, in the example of Dimitre Novatchev, it returns:

```
type="text/xsl" href="test"
```

So the string value of a processing instruction is the data part. select expression of `<xsl:value-of`is evaluated and the resulting object is converted to a string, like a implicit call to the `string()` function.