# How to get processing instruction from XML in Xalan program?

Tags: xalan

Im using Xalan and want to know how to get a processing instruction.
I want to get stylesheet processing instruction.

Thnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the XPath expression to select a Processing instruction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426910/what-is-the-xpath-expression-to-select-a-processing-instruction)

Answer (score 0):

```
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
        XPathEvaluator::initialize();
        {
        const XalanDOMString            theFileName(fileName);
        const LocalFileInputSource      theInputSource(theFileName.c_str());


        XalanSourceTreeInit             theSourceTreeInit;
        XalanSourceTreeDOMSupport       theDOMSupport;
        XalanSourceTreeParserLiaison    theLiaison(theDOMSupport);
        theDOMSupport.setParserLiaison(&theLiaison);

        XalanDocument* const            theDocument =
                                          theLiaison.parseXMLStream(theInputSource);

       if(!theDocument) {
           std::cerr << "Failed to create XalanDocument" << std::endl;
           retValue = -1;
       }

       XalanDocumentPrefixResolver     thePrefixResolver(theDocument);
       XPathEvaluator                  theEvaluator;

       XalanNode* const rootContextNode = theEvaluator.selectSingleNode(
                                                theDOMSupport, theDocument,
                             XalanDOMString("/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')").c_str(),
                                                thePrefixResolver);

       if(rootContextNode) {
//<Now do whatever u want :)>
       }
```