# Apply XSLT stylesheet to it's own output (Filtering out empty elements)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, solr

We're applying an XSL stylesheet to a number of XML files, with different structures, and tags.
We want to use a single XSL stylesheet to all of our files, where we can simply add new xpaths if XML files with new content structures are added.

(I might add that this is for use with Solr from Apache, the output document needs to look a certain way.)

So far we've managed to write the code that copies the various fields, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="fileName" />
    <xsl:param name="fileURI" />
    <xsl:param name="timeCreatedLong" />
<add>
    <doc>
        <!-- REQUIRED FIELDS. DO NOT CHANGE -->
            <field name="fileName"><xsl:value-of select="$fileName" /></field>
            <field name="fileURI"><xsl:value-of select="$fileURI" /></field>
            <field name="timeCreatedLong"><xsl:value-of select="$timeCreatedLong" /></field>
        <!-- //END OF REQUIRED FIELDS -->

        <!-- DSV INTERNAL XML -->
            <!-- Consignment Identifiers -->
            <field name="consignmentIdentifiers"><xsl:value-of select="//consignmentlist/consignment/consignmentId" /></field>
            <field name="consignmentIdentifiers"><xsl:value-of select="//consignmentlist/consignment/references/reference[@type = 'consignment_number']/value" /></field>
            <!-- //Consignment Identifiers -->

            <!-- Transport company information -->
            <field name="carrier"><xsl:value-of select="//transport/transportservice/carriername" /></field>
            <field name="carrierService"><xsl:value-of select="//transport/transportservice/carrierservicename" /></field>
            <field name="transportMode"><xsl:value-of select="//transport/transportservice/transportmode" /></field>
            <!-- //Transport company information -->
        <!-- //DSV INTERNAL XML -->
        

        
        <!-- POSTEN NORDIC LOGISTICS ORDER.XML -->
            <!-- Consignment Identifiers -->
            <field name="consignmentIdentifiers"><xsl:value-of select="//TransportJob/Consignment/@consignmentId" /></field>
            <!-- //Consignment Identifiers -->

            <!-- Transport company information -->
            <field name="definedBy"><xsl:value-of select="//TransportJob/@definedBy" /></field>
            <field name="carrier"><xsl:value-of select="//TransportJob/@profile" /></field>
            <!-- //Transport company information -->
        <!-- //POSTEN NORDIC LOGISTICS ORDER.XML -->
    </doc>
</add>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output, depending on which file structure was processed, looks something like this:

```
<add>
<doc>
    <field name="fileName">00373323993931432015_BOOKING.INTERNALXML</field>
    <field name="fileURI">/usr/dropbox/Dropbox/shared/file-search/00373323993931432015_BOOKING.INTERNALXML</field>
    <field name="timeCreatedLong">1377507872000</field>
    <field name="consignmentIdentifiers"/>
    <field name="consignmentIdentifiers">00373323993931432015</field>
    <field name="carrier">DSV</field>
    <field name="carrierService">DSV Mypack</field>
    <field name="transportMode">ROAD</field>
    <field name="consignmentIdentifiers"/>
    <field name="definedBy"/>
    <field name="carrier"/>
</doc>
</add>
```

As you can see, we have some empty / self-closing elements, which we would wish to remove before sending it to our Solr server.

So the real question is, is there a way to remove the generated empty tags, after applying this XSL to it?
As stated above, we would like this to be done in the same XSL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion to improve things to have a couple of generic templates to match elements or attributes, but which take a parameter which can be set to the 'name' of the field you wish to output.

The first template would actually output the **field** element, setting the name attribute accordingly

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:param name="fieldName" />
    <field name="{$fieldName}">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </field>
</xsl:template>
```

The other one would be used to ignore such elements or attributes without a value:

```
<xsl:template match="*[normalize-space()='']|@*[normalize-space()='']" />
```

(Note that, the more specific template (the one with the Xpath expression checking for an empty string) will get priority here, over the non-specific ones.)

Then, instead of writing this:

```
<field name="consignmentIdentifiers">
    <xsl:value-of select="//consignmentlist/consignment/consignmentId" />
</field>
```

You would write this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//consignmentlist/consignment/consignmentId">
    <xsl:with-param name="fieldName" select="'consignmentIdentifiers'" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

And similar for all the other fields you wish to output. Thus, you don't have to worry about writing **xsl:if** statement around each statement. It is just a slight change to what you are doing at the moment.

**EDIT: If you really wanted to apply the XSLT to its own output...**

Then the way to do this is using a 'two-pass transform'. Ideally, you would use two XSLTs here, but if you wanted to do one, then one the 'first pass' instead of simply outputting the new elements, you wrap the existing code in a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="HereBeDragons">
   <add>
      <doc>
          <field ...
      </doc>
   </add>
</xsl:variable>
```

So, you now have a variable containing your current output, complete with empty tags. Now, if you were using XSLT 2.0, you can just do this to start looking for template matches for elements in the variable

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$HereBeDragons/*"/>
```

But in XSLT 1.0, you will probaly get a message about it not being a node-set. In XSLT 1.0, the variable is actually storing a 'result tree fragment', and needs to be converted to a node-set to allow templates to be used. It looks like you are using EXSLT here, so you should be just able to do this, in this case

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($HereBeDragons)/*" />
```

Now, having started to apply templates on the variable, you can just add templates to process the data as you want. You would have one template for the indentity template

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

And another, to ignore your empty fields

```
<xsl:template match="field[normalize-space()='']" />
```

Be wary though, these templates would apply to both the first-pass and second pass. If you wanted a template that matched a specific element that behaved differently in the second pass, you may need to make use of the **mode** property on the template to distinguish between them.

Of course, doing a two-pass transform in this way is not that efficient, both in terms of memory or speed, which is why adding logic to the original XSLT to not output empty tags in the first place is being proposed.

Comment: This indeed looks like a pretty good way of doing it. If no other responses to our question about having i an empty tag check in the same file appears, I will mark this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me a working example on xsltcake.com? Would be lovely, thanks

Comment: We figured it out :) It's a bit user-unfriendly, but it improves performance some. If it were possible to actually process empty tags, and remove them, depending on the XSL output, I would like to know. Regards

Comment: With much reluctance, I have expanded my answer to say how to do this. Don't do it, kids!

Comment: @Tim: thank you for your post and your ideas on this question. Best regards, Peter +1

Comment: @TimC Thanks again for your anwser. We have a new problem, with wich we could need some help with. Is it possible to extract processing instructions / <? ?> elements with XPath? We need to, since in one of our xml files, the valuable number we need to extract, is actually declared in an <? ?> tag. Would be best if we could use the current XSLT structure as well. Best regards

Comment: It is possible to extract processing instructions with xpath, yes! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426910/what-is-the-xpath-expression-to-select-a-processing-instruction as an example. If you are still stuck, feel free to ask a whole new question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could add checks in your XSLT that only creates elements if the source is not empty. For example for the field `carrier` you could do:

```
<xsl:if test="not(//transport/transportservice/carriername='')">
 <field name="carrier">
   <xsl:value-of select="//transport/transportservice/carriername" />
 </field>   
</xsl:if>
```

If you do that you would not get empty fields in your output.

EDIT: If you want to check the output there is a very efficient way to do that using the identity-rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[normalize-space()='']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, we know that. But have in mind we have to implement over 100 carriers. Making these if statements for each field (about 6 or 7 fields for each carrier, totaling in about 600-700 fields) is not really the best way. We would want to make an XSLT check on the output, and remove empty tags from there. Thanks

Comment: Hello Robin, see my edited post with an XSLT that you could apply to your source. Best regarsd, PEter

Comment: Thanks Peter. But we do not need to check this on the XML source, we need to check it on the output generated from the XSL. Preferably in the same XSL file. Does that clarify? See our included XSL file above.
Thanks

Comment: Robin, have you applied my last XSLT to your XML output? It copies the payload and matches your <field> elements and gets rid of empty ones. Please apply my last XSLT to your XML output and you will see. Thank you, PEter

Comment: Sorry, Robin, I had not explained it properly.

Comment: So do we add the solution, or just your 2 template elements, after the closing template tag of our main content? Regards

Comment: If possible, could you provide a full integration of the solution into our XSL? You can use pastebin or similar sites. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I think you misunderstood us again. We would not like the empty-tag check to be in a completely separate XSL file. We would like it to be in our main XSL file, which you can see in my original question (Code block #1).
Code block #2 is the result we get right now, to demonstrate the empty tags. We don't want to run the result through another XSL file.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the source XML please and will adapt your XSL so it omits the empty tags. Thank you, Peter

Comment: Hi,
You don't need the source XML. Some of our "<field>" tags are empty since the XPath expression can't find values on that location. This will happen a lot once we add multiple carriers.
We just would want to append our XSL code, to ignore empty tags AFTER the transform has completed.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I don't think it is possible with the restrictions (no checks, check on output but within the same transformation) you have. I went through other threads (http://www.google.ch/#fp=b1d56fdefb799363&q=xslt+omit+empty+elements) which all use the identity-transformation I used in my EDIT: post. Does someone else have a suggestion? Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 (you haven't said), I would do it like this:

```
<xsl:sequence select="
   f:field('carrier', //transport/transportservice/carriername),
   f:field('carrierService', //transport/transportservice/carrierservicename),
   f:field('transportMode', //transport/transportservice/transportmode),
   ..."/>
```

with f:field defined as

```
<xsl:function name="f:field" as="element(field)?">
  <xsl:param name="name" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string?"/>
  <xsl:if test="$value">
    <field name="{$name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </field>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This could indeed work, but we need it to be basically the structure we already have. The real question is, is there a way to apply a template on the output of the previous template? But still within the same file? Regards

Comment: >"but we need it to be basically the structure we already have." In my experience that's usually bad programming. At any rate, I'm not prepared to give you a poor solution just because you prefer it.

Comment: The whole point of keeping the structure we have now, is to leave it USSER-FRIENDLY. That is the main goal here.

Comment: I don't know your ussers so I don't know what they would regard as usser-friendly.

Comment: The structure we provided in the question. But don't worry, we've got the fix :) Thanks for your help.